# ipfw not available on Mac OS X yosemite?

Tags: mac, firewall, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to use https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle on Mac OS X 10.10 yosemite. But sadly I couldn't find `ipfw`. Is there a way to install it or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6645172), Yosemite is moving to [PF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_%28firewall%29).

Comment: Can I reinstall it or copy from older version of Mac OS to make it work?

Comment: I guess you can. However, I suggest you start with new stuff if you are going to be working for the first time. https://gist.github.com/scy/8122924 is a basic example PF configuration for your reference.

Comment: Sure thing. Always happy to help.